# How do I render (react) images from MySQL DB?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I have successfully posted the image file name and fetched it back, but am stuck on how to render it in a reach ImageGallery component (sourced in)

```
      this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      images: [],
      files: ""
    }
}

onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  var data = {
      images: document.imgAdd.file.value
  }
  console.log("Submit was clicked", data);
fetch("/gallery/images", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(function(response) {
  if (response.status >= 400) {
    throw new Error("Bad response from server");
  }
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);    

}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err)
});
}

componentDidMount() {
  let url = "/gallery/images"
  fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
      }
      return response.json();
  }).then(images => {
      this.setState({images:images});
      console.log(images)
  }).catch(err => {
  console.log('caught it!',err);
  })
}




      render() {

        return (

        <div className="addImg">
           <form className="imgAdditon" name="imgAdd" method="POST" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
```

I'm not getting any error messages, but am not seeing the image displayed on the page

Comment: I had to cut out some of my code so If there is something not making sense, please just ask. Again, I am just looking to fetch from the DB and render the images on the page. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Are you getting images in get method?

Comment: @KrishnaKamal I'm getting back the image address: "C:\fakepath\IMG_2811.JPG" for example...

Comment: instead of an absolute path you want to serve those assets and point them with a url

Comment: Update: I am now getting this type of error: [object%20File]:1 GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20File] 404 (Not Found)